# Start Web API from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, api, winforms

i got a WinForms Project with a WebAPI inside. The WinForms is used to setup all and the API is needed to fetch data from anywhere else. Is it possible, that i start the Web API via Code after the Setup? Or how can i secure, that always API and WinForms is running?

EDIT:
To make it more clear. I got a Web Applicatio, that fetches Data from a Server. To get this data i developed an API. But I'd like to keep the server flexibel. This could maybe change. So my thought was, that I could Setup/Seelect the Server in a WinForms and start in the Background the API. My question is now, is there a possibility to setup the API in the Background of the WinForms and keep the API running after Forms is closed? Hope now is more clear, what I want to do.

Comment: *the API is needed to fetch data from anywhere else* -> I am not sure I understand. Are you hosting an api or do you want to call an external api?

Comment: I use the WinForms to setup the API Details and then get Data from antoher Application from the API. So I'd like to host an API

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a self host webAPI server using a .net task in this simple way:

```cs
webServer = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // configure your services here
        //services.AddMvc(...
    })
    .Configure(app =>
    {
        // configure your app here
        //app.UseMvc();
    })
    .Build();

await webServer.StartAsync();
```

Comment: If i use this way, is it possible, that WinForms create the API, but the API is still runnig if the WinForms is closed??

Comment: You have to call `webServer.StopAsync`

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I stopped working for a few days. This idea led me to success. Thank you very much